# PostGIS ST_Within ST_intersects differing SRIDs

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a layer of points and want to join some data from polygons where the two coincide. I might have several points in one poly.

The points were generated from a CSV as;

`UPDATE t_osab_with_voa_ndr SET geom_point_4258 = ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4258);`

Where they are stated as being ETRS89 projection which is SRID 4258

I'm running into problems as the points have SRID 4258 and the Polys are 27700 I've tried using ;

`ALTER TABLE t_osab_with_voa_ndr
 ALTER COLUMN geom_point_4258 TYPE geometry(point,27700) 
  USING ST_Transform(geom_point_4258,27700);`

When I look in QGIS I see this;

[image]

But when I run;

`create  or replace view v_spatialjoin_northeast_st_within1 as
select * from t_osab_with_voa_ndr , d_geom_northeast  where st_within(t_osab_with_voa_ndr.geom_point, d_geom_northeast.geom);`

I get no results when I can see I should

Question 1.
Can i combine the ST_Within / ST_Interects and specify the SRID in the process or am i better transforming the points first?

EDIT:
Reason for my blanks was SQL problem with ST_Within, but still interested to know if you can set SRID or what is the fastest way to execute this

Comment: shouldn't you transform geom_point_4258?

Comment: @IanTurton Apologies i'd been chopping and changing in postgres to look for a fix, yes i should and have. Same error

Comment: @ThingumaBob good spot but still get no results

Comment: You can use ST_SetSRID/ST_Transform within the query, however, if the query uses a spatial index, this will likely prevent it from being used, as it becomes non SARGABLE. If you have to do a full table scan on the points anyway, then there is no harm, but you would certainly want an index on the polygon table.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça That sounds like the answer to the originally posed question, can you add it. Although i know realise my error was from elsewhere

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça ...screening the board again for oppportunities to throw in 'SARGEable'? :D

Comment: @ThingumaBob. You know I am a big fan of Sargeable.

Comment: @mappingdom. Sure, when I get home later, I will write it up properly.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça oh I know. I do enjoy those kind of smarta** tech terms myself...,)

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of backtics for  SQL formatting. You just need to indent four spaces or use the `{}` button. This will make your code much more legible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the blanks in this instance was due to my query, what worked was rewriting this as below, code taken from good blog post [here](https://datamodelprototype.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/linking-point-data-to-polygon-data-using-qgis-or-postgis-sql/)

`SELECT pts.*, blocks.inspireid as inspire_poly_id
 FROM t_osab_with_voa_ndr AS pts
 INNER JOIN d_geom_northeast AS blocks
 ON st_within(pts.geom_point, blocks.geom);`

Comment: ...actually, that's weird since, although the `(INNER) JOIN ... ON ...` should be faster here than (and the preferred style in general in favour to) a `CROSS JOIN ... WHERE ...`, in the end it should give the same reuslts...

Comment: I'm running the same process in QGIS to double check my code..

Answer (score 1):

For me what works is to use the ST_transforn instead of ST_Set SRID in order to change the SPATIAL REFERENCE SYSTEM. After that the SPATIAL query wtih INNER JOIN or the other one works perfectly. 
Here is the
[explanation.](https://postgis.net/2013/08/30/tip_ST_Set_or_Transform/)